# oracle sql developer not storing unicode

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, oracle, perl

I am inserting a text field from a mysql database into an oracle clob column.

When I do this it appears that the oracle table does not support unicode as the ' and " characters are showing up as ???.

I have to use clob as the text field is much larger then varchar2 can hold.

Thanks in advance for any help provided on this matter.

Perl script to move data from mysql database into the oracle database:

```
sub do_crc_company_overview {

my ($sth_mysql, $sth_oracle);
my $sql_details = <<END_SQL;
select
   tblRecommendations.code,
   tblRecommendations.description,
   tblRecommendations.overview,
   tblRecommendations.performance,
   tblRecommendations.updated
from 
crc.tblRecommendations
where 
tblRecommendations.code not in (
    select
        tblRecommendations.code
    from
        crc.tblRecommendations
    where
        tblRecommendations.code regexp "[0-9]"
)
END_SQL

# variables to bind values to
my ($code, $description, $overview, $performance, $updated);
eval {
    # first clean out the oracle table 
    $sth_oracle = $dbh_oracle->prepare(q{delete from tblRecommendations});
    $sth_oracle->execute;
    # create oracle insertion query
    $sth_oracle = $dbh_oracle->prepare(q{
      insert into
          tblRecommendations (
          code,
          description,
          overview,
          performance,
          updated
          )
      values
          (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    });
    # prepare our select statement for mysql
    $sth_mysql = $dbh_mysql->prepare($sql_details);
    $sth_mysql->execute;
    $sth_mysql->bind_columns(\($code, $description, $overview, $performance, $updated));
    while ( $sth_mysql->fetch ) {
        # feed the data into the tblRecommendations table
        # in the database, which has been cleaned out
        $sth_oracle->execute($code, $description, $overview, $performance, $updated);
    }
};
```

Pulling the data from the oracle database:

```
class CrcCompanyInfo < Sequel::Model(IM.database[:tblRecommendations])
#Only selects companies that have one or more active instruments
set_dataset select(
     :tblRecommendations__code           => :code,
     :tblRecommendations__description    => :crc_description,
     :tblRecommendations__overview       => :crc_overview,
     :tblRecommendations__performance    => :crc_performance,
     )
```

This works as I am able to pull data from other tables in the database.

I have narrowed it down to the following characters not coming through properly.

```
â€œ = left quote = “
â€ = right quote = ”
â€˜ = left single quote = ‘
â€™ = right single quote = ’
â€” = en dash = –
â€“ = em dash = —
â€¢ = hyphen = -
â€¦ = ellipsis = …
```

I have tried doing an update on the oracle table to change these but the oracle table doesn't hold the funny keys it just changes them all to '???' therefore the update didin't work. Can someone give me any insite on how I might update the data before or while it gets input into the oracle database?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, did you tried to investigate why this is happening? read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I have tried changing the encoding setting of oracle sql developer to utf8 then reloading the data. This had no effect. Sorry im new to all this so dont really know what to try.

Comment: How are you saving the text into the CLOB and how are you getting them back, provide example code, that would make it easier for people to help you

Comment: What is the database character set (from `v$nls_parameters`)?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know. It's not in my code. Is there a way for me to find this out? Again sorry I am very new to all this

Comment: Hi I just looked up in oracle sql developer and there is no field for character set in the preferences for NSL. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself.

I just had to force the utf8 flag on all the data being pushed into the oracle database.

code as follows:

```
$description = Encode::decode_utf8($description);
```

Cheers for everyones help.